# How to recover and delete swap file automatically on E325?

Tags: vim

Vim has a nice feature to recover files if previous session was crashed . Vim show something like this when it happened:

```
Swap file "~/Desktop/.file.txt.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

In most cases I recover the file, and its irritating to press <kbd>r</kbd> every time vim crashes.

1. I want recovery to be automatic.

The problem not ends here. Even if the file has been recovered the swap file still exists there, and that prompt appears again.

1. I want swap file to be deleted if recovery occurs.

So each time in such situation, I want to recover silently and delete the swap file.

Comment: how often does your vim crash?

Comment: @Kent Just enough times that I had to ask this here.

Comment: I would love something for this. I often ssh into a local virtual machine. The session closes after about a half-hour of non-use. When I return to my desk, there we are again. Note also that I often use command history with vi -p to open a number of files, and often these are in a selection of directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I think you could use this:

```
augroup AutomaticSwapRecoveryAndDelete
    autocmd!
    autocmd SwapExists * :let v:swapchoice = 'r' | let b:swapname = v:swapname 
    autocmd BufWinEnter * :if exists("b:swapname") | call delete(b:swapname) | unlet b:swapname | endif
augroup end
```

See `:h v:swapchoice`, `:h v:swapcommand`, `:h v:swapname` and `:h SwapExists`

Comment: I edited my answer (`:let` instead of `set`). Try that in a fresh Vim instance (to delete previous autocmd).

Comment: There's still a glitch *(E46)* at startup.

Comment: Note that, in my code, the left hand side of the second asignment is `b:swapname`, not `v:swapname`. Perhaps you've written `v:swapname` both times? Cause that error happens when you try to assign to a `v:...` variable that is not writable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36245/discussion-between-santosh-kumar-and-eleom)

Comment: Edited again. Hope that helps.

Comment: Still a glitch.. `E305: No swap file found for <filename>` when opening a file that was crashed.

Comment: I really would prefer a solution built in to vim.

Answer (score 3):

Since the swap file should exist as long as your are editing the buffer, I woud rather replace the second autocommand of elmart's answer by

```
augroup AutomaticSwapRecoveryAndDelete
    autocmd!
    autocmd SwapExists * :let v:swapchoice = 'r' | let b:swapname = v:swapname 
    autocmd VimLeave * :if exists("b:swapname") | call delete(b:swapname) | endif
augroup end
```

Moreover, that would allow you to use `:DiffOrig`, when in doubt about the difference between swap and original.